# np.loadtxt() How to load every other line from txt file? Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-files

I have a txt file of data that I only want to load in the even lines from.

Is there a way to do this in python without using loops?

Here are the first 10 lines of my data file:

```
1 25544U 98067A   98324.28472222 -.00003657  11563-4  00000+0 0    10
2 25544  51.5908 168.3788 0125362  86.4185 359.7454 16.05064833    05
1 25544U 98067A   98324.33235038  .11839616  11568-4  57349-2 0    28
2 25544  51.6173 168.1099 0123410  88.0187 273.4932 16.04971811    11
1 25544U 98067A   98324.45674522 -.00043259  11566-4 -18040-4 0    32
2 25544  51.5914 167.4317 0125858  91.3429 269.4598 16.05134416    30
1 25544U 98067A   98324.51913017  .00713053  11562-4  34316-3 0    48
2 25544  51.5959 167.1152 0123861  87.8179 273.5890 16.05002967    44
1 25544U 98067A   98324.51913017  .00713053  11562-4  34316-3 0    59
2 25544  51.5959 167.1152 0123861  87.8179 273.5890 16.05002967    44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The np.loadtxt() doesn't have the ability to skip lines unless they are the *first* N lines.  Otherwise you will want to use **np.genfromtxt()**:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    iter = (line for line in f if is_even_line(line))
    data = np.genfromtxt(iter)
```

where is_even_line() is a function that returns a boolean, if the given line is even. In your case, since the first column indicates whether the line is odd or even, is_even_line() could look like this:

```
def is_even_line(line):
    return line[0] == '2'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use a counter and modulo operator:

```
fname = 'load_even.txt'

data = [];
cnt = 1;
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if cnt%2 == 0:
            data.append(line)
        cnt+=1
```

This reads the file line by line, increasing the counter `cnt` after each line, and appending that line to `data` only if the counter value is even which in this case corresponds to an even line number.

For a particular case of `numpy` array you can use this:

```
import numpy as np

fname = 'load_even.txt'

data = [];
cnt = 1;
with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if cnt%2 == 0:
            data.append(line.split())
        cnt+=1

data = np.asarray(data, dtype = float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filename = 'zarya2000data.txt'
a = np.genfromtxt(filename)

evens = []
odds = []
N = 8 #30 #5826 #number of lines


for i in range(N):   #2913*2
    if np.mod(i,2) == 0:
        evens.append(a[i,:])
    else:
        odds.append(a[i,:])

oddsArray = np.asarray(odds)
evensArray = np.asarray(evens)

print 'evensArray', evensArray
print''
print 'oddsArray', oddsArray  
print ''
```

Comment: How about simply this : `evens = a[0::2]` and `odds = a[1::2]` , that would be the proper way and should also be faster.